# How can I rewrite this code to avoid using global variables?

Tags: javascript

This problem has occurred to me again in the past and I used global variables but I'd like to know what other way there is to deal with it.

The code is from [an html5 canvas tutorial](http://billmill.org/static/canvastutorial/move.html) I'm playing with at the moment.

```
var x = 150;
var y = 150;
var dx = 2;
var dy = 4;
var ctx;

function init() {
  ctx = $('#canvas')[0].getContext("2d");
  return setInterval(draw, 10);
}

function draw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,300,300);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x, y, 10, 0, Math.PI*2, true); 
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fill();
  x += dx;
  y += dy;
}

init();
```

What can I do to avoid using global variables?

Comment: Wrap it all in a self-executing function declaration? `(function() { /* your code */ })()`

Comment: Declare them inside the function? I don't see why you shouldn't add these variables to the `window` object if they are used across multiple functions.

Comment: @DCoder As in chumkiu's answer?

Comment: Yes, that was my original suggestion, but [Gabriel Florit's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12876312/1233508) and [Elias Van Ootegem's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12876397/1233508) answers are probably more appropriate.

Comment: @DCoder sorry. Your suggestion was before my answer (I'm very slow to write in english). I deleted it also because Gabriel's answer is more complete :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the module pattern - it's a neat way of providing encapsulation:

```
var app = app || {};
app = (function () {
  var x = 150; // all these variables are private
  var y = 150;
  var dx = 2;
  var dy = 4;
  var ctx;

  var draw = function() { // this method is private
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,300,300);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x, y, 10, 0, Math.PI*2, true); 
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
    x += dx;
    y += dy;
  };

  return {
    init: function() { // this method is public
      ctx = $('#canvas')[0].getContext("2d");
      return setInterval(draw, 10);
    }
  }
}());

app.init(); // init() is public, but all the other vars and functions are not
```

Read more about it at http://addyosmani.com/largescalejavascript/#modpattern.

Answer (score 3):

You can use an object, as illustrated [here](http://jsfiddle.net/RCJK7/)

```
myObj = {
    x: 150,
    y: 150,
    dx: 2,
    dy: 4,
    ctx: null,
    init: function() {
        this.ctx = $('#canvas')[0].getContext("2d");
        return setInterval((function(a){return function(){a.draw()}})(this), 10);
    },
    draw: function() {
        this.ctx.clearRect(0,0,300,300);
        this.ctx.beginPath();
        this.ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, 10, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
        this.ctx.closePath();
        this.ctx.fill();
        this.x += this.dx;
        this.y += this.dy;
    }
}

myObj.init();
```

**IMPORTANT** Full disclosure, <strike>this code is not working as is</strike>. While I stand by my general approach, the setInterval still needs to be passed the correct context. I have fixed my answer to reflect the above and added a working example to the fiddle link. If the context passing is confusing for you, please use the other approaches.

Comment: thanks, don't really know why I made a fiddle in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Pass them as parameters, and return them modified:

```
function init() {
  var x = 150;
  var y = 150;
  var dx = 2;
  var dy = 4;
  var ctx = $('#canvas')[0].getContext("2d");
  return setInterval(function() {
    var temp = draw(x, y, dx, dy, ctx);
    x = temp.x;
    y = temp.y;
  }, 10);
}

function draw(x, y, dx, dy, ctx) {
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,300,300);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x, y, 10, 0, Math.PI*2, true); 
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fill();
  x += dx;
  y += dy;
  ret = {};
  ret.x = x;
  ret.y = y;
  return ret;
}
```

(I'm not entirely sure what needs to be passed; if you can do so, pass less so as to reduce coupling.)

This solution is, however, inferior to a more class-like method, such as one proposed by @Asad.

Answer (score 1):

It's tempting, and indeed easy just to wrap everything in an object, or an IIFE, which takes care of globals, but that doesn't really bring anything new to the party. I'd suggest a simple closure, where all the variables are set inside the `init` function. In this function we define the `draw` function, so that function has access to the closure vars. Since that function is only used to set an interval, I left out the name, because there simply is no need to have a named function in this closure.

```
var init = function()
{
    var x, y, dx, dy, ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
    return setInterval(function()
    {
        ctx.clearRect(0,0,300,300);
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(x, y, 10, 0, Math.PI*2, true); 
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.fill();
        x += dx;
        y += dy;
    },10);
};
var iv = init();//<-- best off storing the interval somewhere
//... stop drawing:
clearInterval(iv);
```

That's all there is too it.